# Perform actions on a currently running process

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am currently trying to write a script which will retrieve some information from a website which is protected by Windows Security authentication prompt.

Here's a piece of code which I use to enter credentials:

```
$wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
$wshell.Run("iexplore.exe $url_session_tool")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000
$wshell.sendkeys("$login")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("$password")
$wshell.sendkeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```

The problem is, iexplore is running as WScript.Shell object which doesn't really support any functions that would help me retrieve some information I am looking for from the IE website.

Is there any way to import the running iexplore.exe process as InternetExplorer.Application object? Something like:

```
Select-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
```

Perhaps there's another (easier or more complicated) way to deal with this problem?

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

With Invoke-WebRequest you can supply credentials for authentication.

```
$cred = get-credential
invoke-webrequest -uri $url -credential $cred
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx

Comment: It doesn't quite work. The credentials that are used to enter this website are not Windows credentials, they are application credentials but they are entered in a Windows Security popup.

Comment: This should still work as long as the request for authentication is made with a HTTP Access-Control, it shouldn't matter what back-end is used to actually authenticate the credentials.

Comment: I mean WWW-Authenticate, not Access-Control.